# Reading userSettings data from app.config file

Tags: vb.net, app-config

Here is my app.config

```
<configuration>
  <userSettings>
    <MyProject.My.Settings>
      <setting name="IP">
        <value>127.0.0.1</value>
      </setting>
    </MyProject.My.Settings>
   </uesrSettings>
</configuration>
```

I tried :

```
My.Settings.IP
```

and

```
TryCast(ConfigurationManager.GetSection("FormProcessing.Designer.My.MySettings"),My.MySettings)
```

I also tried many other ways and went through so many sites but still didn't get any way to work. I don't want to move it to  as well.

Comment: Search MSDN for ConfigutationManager.AppSettings They provide VB code to read and write settings. For me, it uses [ApplicationName].exe.config not app.config

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
        <section name="MyProject.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <userSettings>
    <MyProject.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="IP" serializeAs="String">
        <value>127.0.0.1</value>
      </setting>
    </MyProject.Properties.Settings>
  </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

Call it MyProject.Properties.Settings.Default.IP

However, the easiest way to create a Property should be, go to menu *View / Solution Explorer*. Navigate to *[Your solution] / [Your project] / My Project / Settings.settings* and double click *Settings.settings*. On the left panel go to *Settings*. Add a row **Name** IP, **Type** String, **Scope** User, **Value** 127.0.0.1. On the top there is an access Modifier, I will leave it as friend. Then just use `[Your Project].Properties.Settings.Default.IP`

Comment: When I try to access IP it doesn't come up.

Comment: 'MyProject.Properties.Settings' is not accessible in this context because it is 'Friend'. - I ended up with this error. I went to some sites which suggest changing the modifier but I am not able to find it in properties.